# How do I write Facebook apps using Django?

Tags: django, facebook, social-networking, pinax

Am in the process of developing some app for Facebook using Django! I've started first by building the app in Django and its shaping up pretty well, now am wondering how can I make it a Facebook app.

I would really appreciate real world example for Facebook apps made with Django.

Answer (score 27):

I just saw the [**presentation**](http://blip.tv/file/3261337) of [***Mr. Eric Florenzano***](http://www.eflorenzano.com/) at **Pycon 2010**, and he talks about a side project he did on facebook using django.

From PYCON 2010:

> If you've been using Django for any
>   amount of time, you've probably
>   learned some pretty standard practices
>   on how to use it. This talk aims to
>   shatter those conceptions and teach
>   you alternative ways that you could
>   use Django.
>
> These alternate ways
>   come broadly in two varieties: Using
>   parts of Django outside of it, and
>   choosing alternatives to what Django
>   offers. If you haven't done either of
>   these things before, it may seem
>   tricky or difficult. In fact, it may
>   not be.
>
> This talk will walk you
>   through the process and talk about
>   what to expect if your project just
>   doesn't seem to "fit the mold".

I recommend you check out his blog and the presentation.

- Blog: http://www.eflorenzano.com/
- Presentation: http://blip.tv/file/3261337

More Resources:

1. [How to build a Facebook app in Django](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/02/how-to-build-a-facebook-app-in-django/)
2. [Example Facebook application in Django](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/example-facebook-application-django/)
3. [Two-Faced Django Part 1: Building a
   project that exists simultaniously
   on Facebook and the web](http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/04/two-faced-django-part-1-building-project-exists-si/)

   - [Two-Faced Django Part 2: Models and Django Testing](http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/04/two-faced-django-part-2-models-and-django-testing/)
   - [Two-Faced Django Part 3: Newforms](http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/04/two-faced-django-part-3-newforms/)
   - [Two-Faced Django Part 4: The Webapp](http://lethain.com/entry/2007/dec/09/two-faced-django-implementing-most-webapp/)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to get started, check out [Fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango) on github.  Its a simple middleware layer that adds a `facebook_user` attribute to the request object when the user is logged in, and sets it to None when they are not logged in.  It also has an easy way to call the Graph API with the users' credentials.

Note: It only works on Facebook Apps.  Websites using facebook connect use a slightly different protocol.

Also note: Any library that references 'pyfacebook' is using the old FB API and you should avoid that.  <strike>The new one that uses the Graph API is [python-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk).</strike> You shouldn't use python-sdk either since its deprecated - thanks @pydanny.  I haven't researched it, but [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) looks actively maintained.

Comment: The python-sdk is not maintained. Don't use it unless you want anguish.

Answer (score 5):

Python Sdk is rather badly maintained.
Think you best option is Django Facebook:
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Basic tutorial
http://www.mellowmorning.com/2011/06/23/django-facebook-2-0-integrating-facebook/

Comment: Also see http://www.mellowmorning.com/2011/06/23/django-facebook-2-0-integrating-facebook/

Answer (score 4):

Info:

[here](http://www.chickenwingsoftware.com/scratches/python/django-facebook-1), [here](http://www.chickenwingsoftware.com/scratches/python/django-facebook-2) and [here](http://www.chickenwingsoftware.com/scratches/python/django-facebook-3) + [pyFacebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PythonPyFacebookTutorial).

Comment: This is all very outdated. PyFacebook is a wrapper around an API that is not available anymore.