# How to develop applications for facebook?

Tags: asp.net, django, facebook

I have a choice between ASP.NET (preferably MVC) and Python (Django only).
Which toolkit is more stable?
I have read the comments section of the Facebook Developer Toolkit and it seems that a lot of people aren't happy with it, is there an alternative?
What about Python libraries for facebook, are there any good libraries to develop facebook applications?
Could you guys provide tutorials and tips for how to develop applications for facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC is a perfectly acceptable choice if you go with the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/). It is an excellent framework and is being updated extremely frequently. You also get all the advantages of developing in .NET and the Visual Studio environment.

Comment: I've read some horrible reviews about it, got any experience with it?

Comment: Yeah I have, I'm not sure where you are getting these reviews from? I am fairly active in the forums and will be happy to assist you. I'd like to reiterate that this is not the SDK that Facebook endorses, it is fairly new and tuned to use the Graph api

Comment: Sorry I was talking about the one that Microsoft supports: http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, go with Django. It has a vibrant community and awesome support.

Second, http://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/ works perfectly with Django. One main problem with Facebook API is that it's changing pretty often, so you need to keep it up to date, from time to time. Tests are a must.

Here is a similar question which should answer your doubts: [How do I write Facebook apps using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650382/how-do-i-write-facebook-apps-using-django)

Comment: Is the Facebook Developer Toolkit for .Net really that bad?

Comment: I don't want to go into a flame-war, but .NET vs Python are two seriously different platforms and environments. There is no "best" without "fit". Best fit should be your guide.

Comment: The original 'Microsoft' one hasn't been updated in ages and you should just forget about it. It's been dropped my Microsoft. The one I suggested is being very actively updated and is soon to hit Release 3. It is also aimed towards MVC development

Comment: Why does the term MVC come up around here? Of course it's for MVC, anything that isn't should not even be mentioned :)